# Copying an Image to PictureBox using ROI EmguCV C#

Tags: emgucv, roi

I want to copy an image from camera to anothe imagebox using ROI. I have searched a lot references about ROI but it still doesn't work. Anybody can help me, please ?
These are what I have done

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImage1 = CaptureCam1.QueryFrame();
SourceImageBox.Image = sourceImage1;
ImageCopy = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(Template_Box.Width, Template_Box.Height);
sourceImage1.ROI = new Rectangle(SourceImageBox.Location.X, SourceImageBox.Location.Y, SourceImageBox.Width, SourceImageBox.Height);
sourceImage1.CopyTo(ImageCopy);
Template_Box.Image = ImageCopy;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like below:

```
sourceImage1.ROI = new Rectangle(SourceImageBox.Location.X, SourceImageBox.Location.Y, SourceImageBox.Width, SourceImageBox.Height);

Template_Box.Image = sourceImage1.clone();
```